# Plus One Linked List: Functional Approach

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Been banging my head on this leetcode problem. Wondering if there is a functional way to approach this. All I can come up with is using mutable objects(In Scala).

Given a non-negative integer represented as a linked list of digits, plus one to the integer.

The digits are stored such that the most significant digit is at the head of the list.

Example 1:

Input: head = `[1,2,3]`
Output: `[1,2,4]`

Example 2:

Input: head = `[0]`
Output: `[1]`

Constraints:

The number of nodes in the linked list is in the range `[1, 100]`.

```
0 <= Node.val <= 9
```

The number represented by the linked list does not contain leading zeros except for the zero itself.

```
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * class ListNode(_x: Int = 0, _next: ListNode = null) {
 *   var next: ListNode = _next
 *   var x: Int = _x
 * }
 */
object Solution {
    def plusOne(head: ListNode): ListNode = {
        
    }
}
```

More interesting input/output = `[1,9,9,9,9] => [2,0,0,0,0]`

Comment: Btw the definition of `ListNode` is not very Scala-like, it should at least be `class ListNode(val x: Int = 0, val next: ListNode = null)`, although the `null` should be replaced with some object representing an empty list node.

Comment: I don't disagree. Just the way leetcode defined it.

Comment: You might want to try some online resources tailored specifically to Scala. This article has a [list](https://analyticsindiamag.com/top-10-free-online-resources-for-learning-scala/) (I haven't tried any of the courses there, though, so I can't testify as to their usefulness).

Answer (score 2):

*(tail)* Recursion to the rescue!

```scala
type Digit = Int // Refined [1..9]
type Number = List[Digit]

def plusOne(number: Number): Number = {
  def sumDigits(d1: Digit, d2: Digit): (Digit, Digit) = {
    val r = d1 + d2
    (r % 10) -> (r / 10)
  }
  
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: Number, remainder: Digit, acc: Number): Number =
    remaining match {
      case digit :: digits =>
        val (result, newRemainder) = sumDigits(digit, remainder)
        loop(remaining = digits, newRemainder, result :: acc)
      
      case Nil =>
        if (remainder != 0) remainder :: acc
        else acc
    }
    
  loop(remaining = number.reverse, remainder = 1, acc = List.empty)
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```scala
plusOne(List(1, 2, 3))
// res: Number = List(1, 2, 4)
```

---

You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/MscWFx8pTkWmTbS3kbFU8A/4).

Comment: This is a very elegant answer but the function takes a `ListNode` and must return a `ListNode`

Comment: @w33b yeah I do not like **Leetcode** for learning **Scala**, most of their problems are intended to be solved in a mutable way and it doesn't give you access to the stdlib which is way more important to learn that use that weird `ListNode` that nobody will ever use in real life.

Comment: @w33b It can't be too hard to adapt this answer to use with `ListNode`. I kinda prefer this over the accepted answer, since it appears to be more efficient and looks more straightforward.

Comment: @w33b [Here's](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/qRObTNHeSYGQw7A0XKfRbg) an adapted version. It's messy, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach:

```
class ListNode(_x: Int = 0, _next: ListNode = null) {
  var next: ListNode = _next
  var x: Int = _x
}

def toNode(l: List[Int]): ListNode = {
  l.foldRight[ListNode](null)((x, acc) => new ListNode(x, acc))
}

def toList(node: ListNode): List[Int] =
  Iterator.iterate(node)(_.next).takeWhile(_ != null).map(_.x).toList

def plusOne(head: ListNode): ListNode = {
  val l0 = toList(head)
  val l1 = List(1)
  val res = l0.reverse.zipAll(l1, 0, 0).foldLeft((List.empty[Int], 0)){
    case ((acc, c), (x0, x1)) =>
      val s = x0 + x1 + c
      if (s >= 10) (s-10 :: acc, 1) else (s :: acc, 0)
  }
  toNode(if (res._2 == 0) res._1 else 1 :: res._1)
}
```

Note that rather than converting ListNode elements to numbers that might be problematic for large ListNodes, `fold` is used to perform iterative element-wise summation.

Testing the code:

```
toList( plusOne( toNode(List(0)) ) )
// res0: List[Int] = List(1)

toList( plusOne( toNode(List(1, 2, 3)) ) )
// res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 4)

toList( plusOne( toNode(List(2, 9, 9)) ) )
// res2: List[Int] = List(3, 0, 0)

toList( plusOne( toNode(List(9, 9, 9)) ) )
// res3: List[Int] = List(1, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Well since you mention performance it would be better to use `reverseItertator` instead.

Comment: My note re: large ListNodes was more about avoiding numeric overflow/rounding issues than performance.  Agreed that it could be further refined if performance is a priority.

Answer (score 1):

Not very efficient solution, but for sure the shortest:

```
(List(1,2,3).mkString.toInt + 1).toString.toList.map(_.asDigit)
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/1Oa4BrbOTgiqMlAwY9SK4Q)

In Scala 2.13 you can use `List.unfold`:

```
def increaseLast(list: List[Int]): List[Int] = List.unfold(list) {
  case Nil =>
    None
  case x :: Nil =>
    Some((x + 1) % 10, Nil)
  case x :: xs if xs.forall(_ == 9) =>
    Some((x + 1) % 10, xs)
  case x :: xs =>
    Some(x, xs)
}
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/oWXLqkaaStO3ffuPbF6Tcg/1).